# Trigger a function in TabBar based on a Floating button from parents

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter for my app.

I have a TabBarView that I would loop as shown as below.

```
  TabBarView(
    controller: controller,
    children: visibleTab
        .map((e) => 
        TabDataWidget(
          data: e, 
          )
        ).toList(),
    );
```

Each Tab would be populated by the TabDataWidget (as shown above).

I have a Floating button, that I wanted to trigger a function inside the TabDataWidget when the user click at the Floating button.

If the user scroll to Tab Index 1, when the user clicks at the Floating button, I wanted to call a function inside TabDataWidget to process data inside Tab Index 1. Similarly, if the user scrolls to Tab Index 2, when the user clicks at the Floating button, I wanted to call a function inside TabDataWidet.

How can I achieve this in Flutter?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need a state management solution as you want to access your data/methods from several widgets. Having a widget calling another widget's function to change state is not recommended as it can get messy and difficult to manage your state. Instead you should lift your state up in the hierarchy and use this state across the widgets you want. Flutter Docs have [a great article](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) that explains how you can approach state management. Different solutions exist but you might have a look at the [provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider). Also there is a [useful talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_m5csmrf7I) by the Flutter team explaining common anti patterns and how provider can help to overcome these.